# Example 3.32 - Algebraic Geometry and Atithmetic Curves, of Qing Liu

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Can anyone explain me why $k(x)=k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha$?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The residue field at a point $x\in X$ is by definition
$$
k(x) := \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x,
$$
where $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is the stalk of the structure sheaf of $X$ at $x$, and $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is its maximal ideal. If you choose an affine open $\operatorname{Spec} A\subseteq X$ containing $x$, then $k(x)$ may be computed in the following way: the point $x$ corresponds to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$, and we have
$$
\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \cong\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A,\mathfrak{p}}\cong A_\mathfrak{p},
$$
where $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$. This has maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$.

In your case, $X$ is already affine, so we can take all of $X$ to be the affine open $\operatorname{Spec}A$ containing $x$. Now, $x$ is the point in $X$ corresponding to the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_\alpha = (T_1 - \alpha_1,\dots, T_n - \alpha_n)$, so we have
$$
k(x) = \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x\cong \left(k[T_1,\dots, T_n]/I\right)_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha\left(k[T_1,\dots, T_n]/I\right)_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}.
$$
Localization commutes with taking quotients, so we have
\begin{align*}
k(x) &\cong \left(k[T_1,\dots, T_n]/I\right)_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha\left(k[T_1,\dots, T_n]/I\right)_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}\\
&\cong \left(k[T_1,\dots, T_n]_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}/I_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}\right)/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha\left(k[T_1,\dots, T_n]_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}/I_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}\right)\\
&\cong k[T_1,\dots, T_n]_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha k[T_1,\dots, T_n]_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}\qquad\textrm{(3rd ring isomorphism theorem)}\\
&\cong \left(k[T_1,\dots, T_n]/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha k[T_1,\dots, T_n]\right)_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}\\
&\cong k[T_1,\dots, T_n]/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha\cong k.
\end{align*}

Comment: Is it then true that the stalk of an affine scheme at $x=\mathfrak {p}$ is equal to $A/\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: The stalk at $\mathfrak{p}$ is isomorphic to $A$ localized at $\mathfrak{p}$, not the quotient of $A$ by $\mathfrak{p}$. See [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/chapter-5.pdf) (proposition 5.1.12 (i)) or [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01HR) (in the case of a module over $A$) for relevant details.

Comment: Or [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Ullery.pdf). The initial definition of structure sheaf here is slightly different, although you get the same end result. I prefer this construction of $\mathcal{O}_X$ to the one described in my first link.

Comment: I Thinked: $(A/\mathfrak{p})_\mathfrak{p}\cong A/\mathfrak{p}$. If it is not true, then how I can verify $k[T_i,\ldots , T_n]/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha\cong \left(k[T_1,\dots, T_n]/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha k[T_1,\dots, T_n]\right)_{\mathfrak{m}_\alpha}$?

Comment: This works because $k[T_1,\dots, T_n]/\mathfrak{m}_\alpha$ is already a field, so everything anything outside (the image of) $\mathfrak{m}_\alpha$ already has an inverse, and localization does nothing. In the general case where $\mathfrak{p}$ is only prime, $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is not necessarily a field, and so localizing will have a nontrivial effect.

Comment: In general, for $\mathfrak{p}$ prime, you'll have $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}\cong (A/\mathfrak{p})_\mathfrak{p} \cong (A/\mathfrak{p})_{(0)} = \operatorname{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p})$.